# How to fix htaccess rewriting for an encoded url

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

Hi I'm having an issue with matching special chars and '+' sign. For example:

```
http://awesome-gallery.engagefb.com/gallery/video/Tv+Shows
```

is matched with this regex:

```
RewriteRule ^gallery/(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?media=$1&gallery-name=$2
```

But when I echo 'gallery-name' in php it returns 'tvshows' not 'tv+shows'

I'd like to run urldecode(gallery-name) and return 'tv shows'

What am I doing wrong in the regex?

Comment: I am getting `tv show` as you like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am getting `Tv Shows` as you like

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^gallery/(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?media=$1&gallery-name=$2
```

index.php

```
<?php
var_dump($_REQUEST);
```

URL: `http://localhost/gallery/video/Tv+Shows`

display:

```
array (size=2)
  'media' => string 'video' (length=5)
  'gallery-name' => string 'Tv Shows' (length=8)
```

Comment: Ok Thanks!! I appreciate the verification